# Creating screen shots for app submission.

Tags: iphone, submit

When submitting screen grabs for an iPhone app during the approval process, is it ok to submit screens that are different than what is represented on the app itself?

For example, I want to submit a screen where I explain some of the features of the app but not necessarily a screen grab.

Answer (score 4):

As Mark mentioned, this seems to be accepted fairly often, though personally I would not encourage it. When I see images like those in the screenshot collection I'm immediately suspicious. Your app should be simple enough that the screenshots show the user what is available. What your screenshots do not convey, you can explain in the text that you submit

Comment: Agreed.  I don't recommend this, as it doesn't look very professional.  Any features should be concisely described within your text listing.  Walkthrough videos on your supporting website can help explain things that text and images can't convey.

Answer (score 1):

People seem to do it fairly often - I've seen several cases where the "screen shots" were something else entirely. I think as long as you're not deliberately misleading, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should submit screen grabs no matter what, I don't recall seeing any  app screenshots without screen grabs. Screen grabs project the ideas, even better with copy to highlight your app features.

If design is a problem, it could be as simple as using device mockups to wrap around your screenshots, the most common style is like this: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/evernote-stay-organized/id281796108?mt=8
plain backgrounds and one sentence per screenshot. Also you'd want to keep the copy short and to the point.

I've used launchkit but they're no longer accepting new sign ups. If you're not an existing user you can try mockuphone